# Sencha nested list remove item selection latency

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a simple nesded list like

```
    var treestore = Ext.create("Ext.NestedList", {
    fullscreen: true,
    updateTitleText: false,
    useTitleAsBackText: false,
    defaultBackButtonText: null,}
```

The problem is when i tap on an item  it changes its own style only after a second holding, though there is need to pass that immediately
Any help will be perfect). thanks

The answer is very simple
i just had to write active atribute for the class displaing items ie :

```
.nav-element:active{
 background:red;
}
```

Comment: Doubt. where do you applied nav-element css class ?

Comment: my item itemtpl was  <div class="nav-element">{filpage}</div>